# Time derivative of unit velocity vector?

Tags: classical-mechanics, acceleration, vector-fields, calculus

Let's say I have some parametric curve describing the evolution of a particle $\mathbf{r}(t)$. The velocity is $\mathbf{v}(t) = d\mathbf{r}/dt$ of course. I am trying to understand what the expression for $$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\mathbf{v}}{\Vert\mathbf{v}\Vert}$$
is. I think it should have something to do with the perpendicular acceleration to the particle's tangent vector, but I can't seem to get any meaningful expression that would tell me this. Helping hand would be appreciated here.

Comment: See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/646088/83835).

Answer (score 1):

As the magnitude of a unit vector cannot change, $\dfrac {d\hat v}{dt}$ is related to the rate of change of the **direction** of the velocity.

Answer (score 1):

The following is valid for any unit vector $q=Q/|Q|$, where $Q$ is a function $Q: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^D$.
Therefore, $q(s)$ is a curve in $\mathbb{R}^D$ such that $|q(s)|=1$ for all values of the real parameter $s$.
Given that $|Q| =\sqrt{Q\cdot Q}$, direct calculation gives:

$$
\frac{dq}{ds}= \frac{d }{ds} \frac{Q}{\sqrt{Q\cdot Q}}
= \frac{1}{|Q|}\perp \frac{dQ}{ds} \, ,
$$

where $\perp$ is the operator that projects any vector on the $(D-1)$-dimensional  subspace orthogonal to $q$.
In index notation (using [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation#Common_operations_in_this_notation)):

$$
\frac{dq_i}{ds}= \frac{1}{|Q|}\perp_{ij} \frac{dQ_j}{ds}
$$

where $\perp_{ij}=\delta_{ij}-q_i q_j$. This is consistent with the idea that the derivative must be orthogonal to $q$, which comes from the fact $d|q|/ds=0$. A totally analogous reasoning is used in special relativity to show that the [4-velocity and the 4-acceleration are "orthogonal"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/601683/226902) or that (as pointed out in the comments) a [centripetal acceleration does not change the speed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/646088/226902).